# Ajax формирование урла с переменными

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь сделать вот такое:

```
<span onClick="sendi(this.id,this.type)" id="2" type="h1">Смотреть</span>



function sendi(clicked_id,clicked_type)  
{  
    var $linked = '/path?' + clicked_type + '&id=' + clicked_id; 
    $.ajax({  
        url: $linked,  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
            $("#cont").html(html);  
        }  
    });  
}
```

Т.е. внутрь урла для ajax мне нужно добавить две переменные (id и type) - упорно выдает ошибку unexpected string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы добавили кастомный атрибут то его можно получить используя метод [getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

```js
function sendi(id, type)  
{
    let $link = '/path?' + type + '&id=' + id; 
    console.log('id => ', id);
    console.log('type => ', type);
    $.ajax({  
        url: $link,  
        cache: false,  
        success: function(html){  
            $("#cont").html(html);  
        }  
    });  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span onClick="sendi(this.id, this.getAttribute('type'))" id="2" type="h1">Смотреть</span>
```